# Two self-referencing one to many relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

This is my first question, so if there are formatting issues or unclear formulations, please don't hestitate to tell me.

I have an entity called Item that, besides other properties has two links to other items("GlobalItem" & "DepositItem") in the same DBSet.

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemID { get; private set; }
 
    public virtual Item GlobalItem { get; set; }

    public virtual Item DepositItem { get; set; }

    protected Item() { }
}
```

The mapping is done like so:

```
 public ItemMap()
    {
        HasKey(o => o.ItemID);

        ToTable("Item", "dbo");

        // Relationships
        HasOptional(o => o.GlobalItem)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("GlobalItemID"));

        HasOptional(o => o.DepositItem)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("DepositItemID"));
    }
```

The build process is successfull, but when I try to GetAll() the following Exception is thrown:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.'
>
> Inner Exception:
>
> SqlException: Invalid column name 'DepositItem_ItemID'.
>
> Invalid column name 'DepositItem_ItemID'.
>
> Invalid column name 'DepositItem_ItemID'.

I know that this exception usually is caused by simple mapping errors, but in this case, i am stuck, as I made sure that the ColumnName and MapKey are correct, and all the usual workarounds like explicitly defining the DepositItemID in the entity and using `.HasForeignKey(k = k.DepositItemID)` instead of the former mapping definition did not change anything.

Does EF6 have a general problem with more than one self referencing virtual property? Can somebody explain to me, why the mapping key is ignored for DepositItem, but not ignored for GlobalItem? Can somebody find a flaw in my design?

Best regards and thank you for your efforts,

Comment: Your GlobalItem and DepositItem  does not have reference but object. Should reference with ItemID which carry object.

Comment: Try to make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
More specifically, make it Minimal; remove code (properties, in this case) that are no use to the problem.

Comment: @JoshuaVdM thanks for your input!

Comment: @Md.AbdulAlim I am not sure, that I understand your suggestion. The DepositItem and GlobalItem are Navigation properties within the item entity and mapped via the respective ids in my mapping definition.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your object should be

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemID { get; private set; }

    public int? GlobalItemID { get; set; }

    public int? DepositItemID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GlobalItemID")]
    public Item GlobalItem { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DepositItemID")]
    public Item DepositItem { get; set; }

    protected Item() { }
}
```

Comment: this conflicts with my mapping and results in an Exception:

System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: 'One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

DepositItemID: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'DepositItemID' is already defined.
GlobalItemID: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'GlobalItemID' is already defined.
'

Comment: Update my code. Make sure your database column name and model property name will same

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't change the outcome.

Changed the mapping to ".HasForeignKey(...)" accordingly for both properties. 
and the result stayed the same.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with that model.  Perhaps your database needs to be recreated.

See:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

namespace Ef6Test
{
    public class Item
    {
        public int ItemID { get; private set; }

        //public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string ItemLookupCode { get; private set; }

        public virtual Item GlobalItem { get; set; }

        public virtual Item DepositItem { get; set; }

        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        //public virtual ItemExtension ItemExtension { get; set; }



        public Item() { }
    }
    class Db : DbContext
    {

       public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasKey(o => o.ItemID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().ToTable("Item", "dbo");

            // Relationships
            //HasRequired(t => t.Category)
            //    .WithMany(o => o.Items)
            //    .Map(m => m.MapKey("CategoryID"));

            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasOptional(o => o.GlobalItem)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(m => m.MapKey("GlobalItemID"));

            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasOptional(o => o.DepositItem)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(m => m.MapKey("DepositItemID"));

            //HasOptional(o => o.ItemExtension)
            //    .WithRequired(o => o.Item);



        }



        class Program
        {


            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Db>());


                using (var db = new Db())
                {
                    db.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m);
                    db.Database.Initialize(true);

                    var items = db.Items.ToList();


                }


                Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Creates

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item] (
    [ItemID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max),
    [ItemLookupCode] [nvarchar](max),
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DepositItemID] [int],
    [GlobalItemID] [int],
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Item] PRIMARY KEY ([ItemID])
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, dropping and recreating that database is no option at this very moment. I will try to create a small DB to verify my problem and your suggestion.

Comment: You were right in terms of the model being correct, my error was in another entity (ItemExtension)

Answer (score 0):

The Item model and mapping are fine.

The issue was caused by an old navigation property, also called "DepositItem", in another entity which was not mapped in the database.